# parent, child, grandchild mapping elasticsearch json parse error

Tags: json, elasticsearch, mapping, parent-child, parse-error

I have already existing index name test-migrate. I want to add the data into it via custom mapping in order to fulfil parent-child-grandchild relation. I am getting the parse error for my specified index. Can you please point out my mistake.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://url:9200/test-migrate'

{"acknowledged":true,"shards_acknowledged":true}
```

Here is how my mapping looks like:

```
curl -XPUT 'url:9200/test-migrate/type/_mapping' -d  '
{
  "type" : {
   "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties" : {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "type" : "date"
      },
      "@version" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "sub" : {
      "properties" : {
            "mnumber" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "pnumber" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "s_id" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "s_name" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
      }
      },
      "comp": {
        "_parent": {
       "type" : "sub"
       },
      "properties" : {
      "comp_id" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "comp_name" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
      }
      },
      "we" : {
       "_parent" : {
      "type"  :  "comp"
      },
      "_routing"  : {
      "type" :  "sub"
      },
      "properties" : {
      "we_1" : {
        "type" : "float"
      },
      "we_2" : {
        "type" : "float"
       }
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
'
```

But when i execute it I get an error message:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [comp] has unsupported parameters:  [_parent : {type=sub}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [comp] has unsupported parameters:  [_parent : {type=sub}]"},"status":400}
```

Comment: elastic version?

Comment: "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.1",
    "build_hash" : "2cfe0df",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.1"
  },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. There was problem with the structure with the mappings structure, mappings of other types has to defined as seperate mapping object.

```
    PUT parent_index
    {
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "@version": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "sub": {
                    "properties": {
                        "mnumber": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "pnumber": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "s_id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "s_name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
        "we": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "comp"
            },
            "_routing": {
                "type": "sub"
            },
            "properties": {
                "we_1": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "we_2": {
                    "type": "float"
                }
            }
        },
        "comp": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "sub"
            },
            "properties": {
                "comp_id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "comp_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** 
Other way which specifically you are looking for.

**First**, create index

```
PUT test-migrate
```

**Second**, Now add mappings for type

```
POST test-migrate/_mapping/type
   {
    "type": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "@version": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sub": {
        "properties": {
            "mnumber": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "pnumber": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "s_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "s_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "we": {
        "_parent": {
            "type": "comp"
        },
        "_routing": {
            "type": "sub"
        },
        "properties": {
            "we_1": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "we_2": {
                "type": "float"
            }
        }
    },
    "comp": {
        "_parent": {
            "type": "sub"
        },
        "properties": {
            "comp_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "comp_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: 
    {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  "status":400}

Comment: can you share the exact mapping you used for the error above

Comment: I used the same json structure as you told me. But, i just noticed that i have used different url. You said PUT parent_index, i used curl -XPUT url:9200/test-migrate/_mapping/type' -d ' (JSON structure from above suggested by you) '.

Comment: hey, i edited my post to add another way to create index. Well this should not matter as if first one works then second one should work, unless something is wrong than mappings.lmk

Comment: Great! works now. What is the main difference, can you explain. Why it works now, not earlier. Curious for the future!

Comment: glad this worked. maybe you missed something while copying mappings, i also just did the same with my mappings. First creating only index, and then posting mapping type. Great it sorted, can you please accept this answer if resolved.